# How to convert RGB to HTML color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hex, uicolor

Please can you tell me how I can convert an RGB `UIColor` to a Hexadecimal HTML color code string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)getHexStringForColor:(UIColor*)color {
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    CGFloat r = components[0];
    CGFloat g = components[1];
    CGFloat b = components[2];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X", (int)(r * 255), (int)(g * 255), (int)(b * 255)];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with non-RGB colors like `[UIColor blackColor]`. The question is only about RGB colors, but if you want to support more `UIColor`s you can use ngb's approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13134326/211292