# How to view a color code in the Xcode xib editor?

Tags: xcode

I've been using a color that I chose with a color picker in Xcode. I need to use that color programmatically now, but I don't know its hex code.

Is there a way to see it in Xcode?

I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about picking color in xcode interface builder, the answer can be obtained in 2 steps:

Step 1: Get RGB values by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565008/how-do-i-enter-rgb-values-into-interface-builder).

Step 2: Convert that to hex code by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002483/how-to-convert-rgb-to-html-color)

Answer (score 15):

As of Xcode 6, users can view both **RGB**, **CMYK**, **HSB** and the **Hex value** as shown below. (No need for conversion)

[image]

Comment: This answer is correct but it is worth noting that colour values must be set to 8 bit (0-255) in order to see the hex value. The hex value will not appear if colour value is set to float (0.0-1.0)

Comment: @arcadybob well if the values are in float then just multiple them with 255 (denormalize) and then you can find the hex value by using the above method.

Answer (score 3):

write this in .m file

1.NSLog(@"color is %@",picker.color);

Comment: Hi, Hitman. I could have been more clear. I used the color picker to set a color for a button's title text. I tried your idea like: `NSLog(@"color:%@",[myButton titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal]);` but got these values: `color:UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.196078 0.309804 0.521569 1`. I guess the 1 is the alpha channel, but I'm not sure what to do with the RGB values.

Comment: [UIColor colorwithRed :blue ]//some function is there.use that

Comment: Thank you. It's `[UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha: ]`.

Answer (score 1):

ColorSense is a very simple xcode extension that makes it easy to do exactly what you needed.

Use as below:

[image]
[image]

Watch the [short video here](http://maniacdev.com/2012/09/tool-uicolor-color-display-and-color-picking-extension-for-xcode) to see how it works.

[You can download the extension here](https://github.com/omz/Colorsense-for-Xcode)