# How to write css for a color when you only know the color in the RGB format

Tags: css, rgb

I changed the title so that it will be more clear in the difference from the duplicate questions.

Let me explain how this question is different from [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)
The previous question is for the general purpose. However this question is only for uses in css. Please understand that many of the readers of this question do not understand the answers of the previous question. Me too.

I know this question seems to duplicate to [How to convert RGB to HTML color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002483/how-to-convert-rgb-to-html-color).

However I think the answer tries to teach more than the original question. In fact, I don't understand the answer and can't use it in the actual code.

Please give me the simplest mathematical formula to translate RGB to the form like #fff which I think represents white.

I know the required color is written as R:63,G:81,B:181 in RGB.

```
    R:63, G:81, B:181
```

And I need to translate the RGB into the CSS format.
Please give me exact CSS color code for the color. Plus please give me the simplest mathematical formula for the translation.

Comment: @DevidFarinelli, Do I need to delete this question? The 5 answers help me a lot and saved a lot time of me. However I don't know the rule here well, so if you say I need then I will delete this question.

Comment: Yes, you can delete the question as you already found the answer here. Or otherwise it will probably be marked as a duplicate (when enough people vote for it) and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the rgb in decimal is the only information you have, you don't need to transfer, simply put

```
color: rgb(61, 81, 181)
```

Comment: Your answer is nice. I guarantee that If this question won't be  deleted as a duplicated question, it will help many many readers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Chrome,
2. Inspect the element which has the color in rgb value,
3. In the styles section, just hold Shift key and click the color box(after color:)..
   You will see colour in hex code, rgb value and hsl value..

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the Hex color, really simple to find. All you need is photoshop or even easier on various online tools such as:

http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hex.htm
http://www.color-hex.com/

For this example the hex color you require is: #3D51B5

Comment: Thank you very much for the exact answer, #3D51B5.

Answer (score 0):

//Just use this function:

```
function rgbToHex(r,g,b){
if( r >= 0 && r <= 255 && g >= 0 && g <= 255 && b>=0 && b<= 255){
    r = Number(r).toString(16); //<- decimal to hexadecimal convertion
    g = Number(g).toString(16); //<- decimal to hexadecimal convertion
    b = Number(b).toString(16); //<- decimal to hexadecimal convertion
    return "#"+ r + g + b;
}

throw new RangeError("rgbToHex:: > r, g and b must be in this range [0,255] .");}
```

//--> uage: rgbToHex(61,81,181)
//--> return: "#3d51b5"

Comment: ,Thank you very much. This is exactly what I asked. I read all 34 questions in the duplicated question. And this answer well fits to my task than them.